# Universal cost function for process control?

Tags: optimization, loss-function

I have a problem of process control which looks like this:

- The outputs of the process are a number of outcome variables 0-100
  where 0 is worst and 100 is best. There is no specific rule (already
  known, or related to the nature of the problem) for how to combine
  them into a single cost function.  There is some intuition about what results are good, however.
- All the variables are equally important, and scaled the same way. 
  The cost function should be symmetric with respect to permutation of
  the values.
- If all the variables are 100 except one is 0, that is a bad
  outcome.
- If all the variables are 90, that is a very good outcome.

The last two statements imply that the right way to combine variables into a cost function is something similar to min(v1, v2, ...).  But that has a problem, in that the direction of optimization would always be determined by the lowest variable alone.

Intuitively, it is desirable to trade off a slight worsening in one variable for a large improvement in another, even if the variable that is getting worse is already pretty bad, for example: 30 and 50 is less preferred than 28 and 75 (or something like that).  This implies some relative elasticity of variables which in this case is close to 100:1 for variables near the opposite ends of the range, and 1:1 for variables which are equal valued.

**How can a good cost function be constructed for this kind of problem in a general-purpose way?**  (with some adjustable parameters for elasticity, etc)

Comment: I think you may need to elaborate on "There is some intuition about what results are good, however." The most obvious combination to me would simply be $J = - \prod_{\forall i} \frac{v_i}{100}$. Other than that, there are very many possible cost functions here, and you don't give any real indication of why you might choose one over another

Comment: @NeilSlater: You are correct.  That's why I want a tunable family of cost functions :)  An example based on your suggestion: product( (v_i/100) ** p ) ** (1/q) for some p, q which can be adjusted until they match intuition.  Intuition can/should also be studied quite rigorously, by giving pairs of scenarios to experts to rank relative to each other.

Comment: Alternatively the log form $J = -\sum_{\forall i} log( \frac{v_i + C}{100} )$ would also be typical. Ultimately that's the same stat, but whether it is useful depends on which algorithm you want to use to optimise the value.